# mgf of Y=X1-X2; in which X1 and X2 are from the same distribution

Tags: moment-generating-functions, exponential-distribution

**If X1 and X2 are iid ~ exp(m) and Y=X1-X2**,
The moment generating function of y would be

$E(e^{ty})=E(e^{t({x1-x2})})=\frac{E(e^{tx1})}{E(e^{tx2})}= \frac{\frac{m}{m-t}}{\frac{m}{m-t}}=1$

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong because in general the expectation of a ratio is not the ratio of the expectations. In other words you cannot write
$$E\left(\frac XY\right)=\frac{E(X)}{E(Y)}.$$
If $Y$ and $X/Y$ were independent, then this would be legal, but it's not true in your case.